# How to take data from Average of Hour ( from a 30 seconds data sheet) in R

Tags: r

I'm working on a huge data sheet in excel which has data in every 30 seconds of a day. . Two columns I need to perform the task are time and power . I'm asked to find the daily power in hour basis . So I need to take the average of each hour from 30 seconds data in R studio . Please help me with it . I'm new to this software .

also its a normal excel sheet with time and power values . but the time is in the formate of dd:mm:yy hh:mm:ss. And I need to plot the graph of power and time (hourly basis) . for a particular day , giving times eg , 8 o clock , 9o clock etc

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit the question with the output of `dout(head(your_data, 20))`.

Comment: Please provide sample data in a copy&paste-able format (e.g. using `dput`) and expected output. It might be useful to take a look at how to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: its a normal excel sheet with time and power values . format of time is date:month:year hour:minute:second . and time is for every 30 seconds .  example 6:21:00 , 6:21:30 , 6:22:00 etc

Comment: @RuiBarradas please check

Comment: You shouldn't post data (or code) as images. Please use `dput` as explained above. Also, you want the averages of what column? The last one, `m_Pm`?

Comment: @RuiBarradas yes the last column , m_Pm

Comment: That is just a matter of changing the variable name in my answer, from `x` to `m_Pm`. Done.

Comment: okay thank you so much @RuiBarradas . Let me try

Comment: @RuiBarradas it is showing current date, i want the output of the date provided :(

Comment: I don't understand, the `format` instruction will keep ymd and hour. Can you post the code you are using?

Comment: @RuiBarradas the answer you provided is perfect . but ,  seq(as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()) - 1, Sys.time(), by = "30 secs") this command makes the data use today's date. and not the date from my data

Comment: @RuiBarradas I need to get daily average of m_pm on hour basis of the date given , for example i want from 2017-09-26 to 2017-09-27 (that's 1day)

Comment: If you want **daily** averages, try `tapply(dat$m_Pm, as.Date(dat$time), mean)` and `aggregate(m_Pm ~ as.Date(time), dat, mean)`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas so still keeping theposixct function same ??

Comment: You are not understanding, `as.POSIXct` is just to make an example dataset, you do **not** need to use it in your code, what you must use is `format` and `tapply` or `aggregate`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas okay sorry , thanks again . I'm new to this ...

Comment: @RuiBarradas okay I got it ! thanks

Comment: @RuiBarradas wont disturb again . just my last doubt ... How to get one day's energy on hourly basis . for example , i want energy of 2017-09-26 in hourly basis , as in 8.o clock , 9 o clock , 10 o clock etc (by taking hourly average ). PLEASE HELP

Comment: You can aggregate by several variables, `aggregate(m_Pm ~ as.Date(time) + h, dat, mean)`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Sir , I still am not able to plot graph for a single day with time. :(

Answer (score 1):

In base R, you can use `tapply` or `aggregate` to compute group means.

First, some fake data, since you have posted none.
The `time` variable is created with `seq.POSIXt`, starts today minus 1 day (`Sys.Date - 1`) and end today (`Sys.time`) by increments of 30 seconds.
The numeric variable is just a gaussian random variable.

```
set.seed(3224)

time <- seq(as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()) - 3, Sys.time(), by = "30 secs")
dat <- data.frame(time, m_Pm = cumsum(rnorm(length(time))))
```

Now, start by getting just the hours, then find group means.

```
dat$datehour <- format(dat$time, "%Y-%m-%d %H")

tapply(dat$m_Pm, dat$datehour, mean)
#2018-08-12 00 2018-08-12 01 2018-08-12 02 2018-08-12 03 2018-08-12 04 
#    0.5159274     8.2868756    24.8056718    26.4107549    27.6064418 
#2018-08-12 05 2018-08-12 06 2018-08-12 07 2018-08-12 08 
#   33.0096640    42.7479312    40.2468852    41.5313523


agg <- aggregate(m_Pm ~ datehour, dat, mean)

head(agg)
#       datehour       m_Pm
#1 2018-08-12 00  0.5159274
#2 2018-08-12 01  8.2868756
#3 2018-08-12 02 24.8056718
#4 2018-08-12 03 26.4107549
#5 2018-08-12 04 27.6064418
#6 2018-08-12 05 33.0096640

As for the graph, I will draw a line graph using package `ggplot2`. The x axis is formated with package `scales` function `scale_x_datetime`.

library(ggplot2)
library(scales)


ggplot(agg, aes(x = as.POSIXct(datehour, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H"), y = m_Pm)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  labs(x = "Hour", y = "Mean value") +
  scale_x_datetime(labels = date_format("%Y-%m-%d %H"))
```

[image]

Comment: time <- seq(as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()) - 1, Sys.time(), by = "30 secs")
dat <- data.frame(time, x = rnorm(length(time)))                                                   
               can you explain me this , please ?

Comment: @FatmaZahra Done, I hope this is it. I have changed everything.

Comment: i'm getting a plot of whole data set. so i cannot get a single day's data ??

Comment: @FatmaZahra You can subset by date if you want. `agg[as.Date(agg$datehour) == as.Date("2018-08-11"), ]`.

Answer (score 0):

It would be much more helpful if you posted a reproducible dataframe.  Anyway, I'll just give you a generic solution...

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text="
date hour temperature
28/12/2013 13:03:01  41.572
28/12/2013 13:08:01  46.059
28/12/2013 13:13:01  48.55
28/12/2013 13:18:01  49.546
28/12/2013 13:23:01  49.546
28/12/2013 13:28:01  49.546
28/12/2013 13:33:01  50.044
28/12/2013 13:38:01  50.542
28/12/2013 13:43:01  50.542
28/12/2013 13:48:01  51.04
28/12/2013 13:53:01  51.538
28/12/2013 13:58:01  51.538
28/12/2013 14:03:01  50.542
28/12/2013 14:08:01  51.04
28/12/2013 14:13:01  51.04
28/12/2013 14:18:01  52.534
28/12/2013 14:23:01  53.031
28/12/2013 14:28:01  53.031
28/12/2013 14:33:01  53.031
28/12/2013 14:38:01  51.538
28/12/2013 14:43:01  53.031
28/12/2013 14:48:01  53.529
28/12/2013 15:01:01  50.77")

means <- aggregate(temperature ~ datehour, df, mean)

# Result:
means
             datehour temperature
1 2013-12-28 13:00:00    49.17192
2 2013-12-28 14:00:00    52.23470
3 2013-12-28 15:00:00    50.77000
```

[image]

Comment: thank you . but how do I select just a day ?? for example I want daily average plot . so I need for example average power of 2017-09-26 8 o clock , 9 o clock data